# Simple factor theorem question: self studying calculus

Tags: calculus

[image]

Why is b a factor of 24 in this example? It is not immediately obvious to me. Also does the factor theorem only work for degrees three and above? What if b was 70? Would I have to plug in each possible b that is a factor of 70 through trial and error until I find one that fits the equation?

Is there a simple proof of the factor theorem?

Comment: Two reasons: $(1)$ $24$ is a factor of $24$ and $(2)$ the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Comment: take a look at [Vieta's Formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) for an idea as to why b divides 24

Comment: You also might want to look up [synthetic division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division) to avoid all that writing that comes with polynomial long division.

Answer (score 0):

If $P(b) = 0$, this implies:

$b^3 -3b^2-10b+24 =0$

$-b^3+3b^2+10b = 24$

$b(-b^2+3b+10) = 24$

$(-b^2+3b+10) = \frac{24}{b}$

Recall that since $b$ is an integer, $(-b^2+3b+10)$ must be an integer.

Therefor, $\frac{24}{b}$ must be an integer, so $b$ must be a factor of 24.

Answer (score 0):

"Why is b a factor of 24 in this example? It is not immediately obvious to me."

This isn't part of the factor theorem but "common sense", if the polynomial factors at at then:$

$(x - b)(x-c)....(x -d) = x^3 -3x^2 - 10x + 24$ then all the b, c, ...d multiplied together will be 24.  So b is a factor of 24.

if it were 70 you'd look for factors of 70.

"Does it only work for degree 3 and more"

No, it works for degrees 2 and 1.  But the quadratic equation and linear solutions make those cases easier.

Proof:

Well, okay... For any polynomial can rewrite P(x) = Q(x)Z(x) + R(x) where the degree of P is equal to the degree of Q plus the degree of Z and the degree of R(x) {the remainder polynomial; what is left when your force the division} is less than the degree of Z or Q.  Basically this is dividing P(x) by Z(x) to get Q(x) plus a remainder polynomial R(x).  You can always do this.  It just might not do you any good.

So we can write: P(x) = Q(x)(x - b) + R(x) where degree of R(x) is less then the degree of (x - b) which is 1.  So the degree of R(x) = 0 so R(x) = r.  For some real number r.

So P(x) = Q(x)(x - b) + r

but if P(b) = 0 the P(b) = Q(b)(b - b) + r = Q(b)0 + r = r.   So r = 0.

So P(x) = Q(x)(x -b) for some polynomial Q(x) so (x -b) divides P(x).